# include <signal.h> error, library is missing

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to compile a code that uses these libraries on Ubuntu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
```

but the compiler returned this error

```
sig.c:3:9: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
 #include <signal.h> 
         ^
```

also for `unistd.h`

is there any way to fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you copy this code or write it yourself?

Comment: Delete the white spaces between the `#include`s and `<`s. Also use an appropriate editor for edtiting code, not a word-processor or another vanilla editor.

Comment: Are your `<` and `>` from some weird character set?

Comment: 1. `signal.h` is a header-file and not a libray. 2. From what are you concluding `signal.h` is missing? The error message expresses that what follows `#include` not cannot be found, but is not interpreted as a filename. Thus, refrain from copypastaing, but delete the line and then use your fingers and retype the line using the keyboard.

Comment: Can you upload the output of `xxd sig.c | head -n 20`?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is reporting a syntax error, not a missing header. The code in your question looks correct, but there must be some strange characters that you're not seeing, perhaps something that looks like a `<` character or a space but really isn't.

Try typing

```
head foo.c | cat -A
```

at a shell prompt; that will show you what's really in your source file. (Substitute your actual file name for `foo.c`, of course.)